# Modprobe ndiswrapper error

Tags: ndiswrapper, modprobe

I'm trying to get my wusb300n card working on my desktop.  I've downloaded ndiswrapper-1.59 and when I run make, everything goes fine except for a warning

```
WARNING: "mcount" [~/Downloads/ndiswrapper-1.59/driver/ndiswrapper.ko] undefined!
```

I am still able to make install it and it works.  However, when I run

```
sudo modprobe ndiswrapper
```

I get

```
ERROR: could not insert 'ndiswrapper': Unknown symbol in module, or unknown parameter (see dmesg)
```

and dmesg gives

```
ndiswrapper: Unknown symbol mcount (err 0)
```

the same name from the make warning.

Some other info:

```
$ uname -r
3.11.0-20-generic

$ sudo modprobe -n -v --first-time ndiswrapper
insmod /lib/modules/3.11.0-20-generic/misc/ndiswrapper.ko
```

I'm on 64 bit Ubuntu 13.10

Answer (score 1):

After countless hours I've finally found the problem.  It turns out I changed the version of gcc in order to install something a while back and that was causing the error.  All I did to fix it was

```
cd /usr/bin
sudo rm gcc
sudo ln -s gcc-4.8 gcc
```

Remake everything, and then adding the ndiswrapper module worked!